# Where is the subject of the sentence "and were enabled"?

Tags: sentence-structure

> The people felt this, without knowing why, and recognized it in every deed or word or touch, so that those who have once felt the grasp of his great warm hand seem to have been drawn into the strong circuit of "Lincoln fellowship," ***and*** ***were*** ***enabled,*** as if by "the laying on of hands," to speak of him ever after with a deep and tender feeling.

My question is where is the subject of "and were enabled"

Comment: The subject of "were enabled" is "those who have once felt the grasp of his great warm hand".

Answer (score 1):

The following clause describes the result of "The people felt this...":

> ... so that **those** who have once felt the grasp of his great warm hand **seem to have been drawn** into the strong circuit of "Lincoln fellowship," and **were enabled**, as if by "the laying on of hands," **to speak** of him ever after with a deep and tender feeling.

The subject of the clause is **those**, and the verbs are **seem to have been drawn** and **were enabled... to speak**.

The pronoun **those** refers to the subset of **the people** who had felt his handshake .